# Firebase functions gen 2 deploy failed and logs not available

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am tryint to deploy SSR function on Firebase functions with gen2.

But it shows error "Syntax error". I've done the same code in Gen1 and currently working in production.

Code:

```
import { setGlobalOptions } from "firebase-functions/v2";
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const mainJSFile = require(__dirname + "/server/main");


setGlobalOptions({ minInstances: 1, maxInstances: 4 });
exports.ngssr = onRequest(mainJSFile.app());
```

Package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"g": "^2.0.1",
"http-server": "^14.1.1",
"xml-sitemap": "^0.3.2",
"angular-feather": "^6.5.0",
"animate.css": "^4.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
"ng2-sticky-nav": "^10.0.0",
"ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^15.0.0",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.12.0",
"firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
```

and all the compiled files store in `/server/` path.

What i get in response

```
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8656

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```